# Printing array struct of struct

Tags: c, struct

I have an array struct that is inside another struct, but I don't know how to print the value of the son struct in a function.

The main struct is something like:

```
 struct person{
    char name[10];
    int cash;
    listMov mov[];
};
typedef person Person;
Person user[50];
```

And the son struct

```
struct listaMovimenti{
    int bonifico;
    char beneficiario[10];
};
typedef struct listaMovimenti listMov;

listMov mov[2] = {{150, "Ponzi" },
                   {2000, "Gotti"}};
```

I've tried with something like this but with no success.

```
printf("Name %s and %d",user[0].mov[1].beneficiario, user[0].mov[1].bonifico);
```

Comment: Define "no success". Did the code fail to compile? Did it crash? etc...etc...

Comment: And also include in your question the code that shows how you're populating `user` too

Comment: This is called *flexible member array* and it doesn't work that way. You must use dynamic allocation if you want to use that.

Comment: @ChrisTurner, beneficiario's string prints blank, the int bonifico prints 0. I populate `user` name and cash through a simply `scanf`.

Comment: But how do you populate `user` `mov`? It's different to the `mov` variable you've included code for

Comment: I don't... I've thought that `mov` in the main struct populate itself with the data for the initialization...

Answer (score 2):

First:

The variable `listMov mov[2]` has no relation to the `listMov mov[];` inside the struct. They have the same name but the scope is different. They are simply completely unrelated.

Second:

```
listMov mov[];
```

means you have a flexible array inside the struct. When you use a flexible array in a struct, you have to use dynamic memory allocation to reserve the amount of memory that you need. Using `Person user[50];` is kind of meaningless as no memory is reserved for the flexible arrays.

Use of flexible arrays is a bit difficult. In most cases it is easier just to use a pointer like:

```
struct person{
    char name[10];
    int cash;
    listMov* mov;
};
typedef person Person;
Person user[50];
```

and then allocate memory like

```
user[0].mov = malloc(N * sizeof(listMov)); // N is thee number of elements needed
```

Then you can do:

```
user[0].mov[0].bonifico = 150;
strcpy(user[0].mov[0].beneficiario, "Ponzi");
user[0].mov[1].bonifico = 200;
strcpy(user[0].mov[1].beneficiario, "Gotti");

printf("Name %s and %d",user[0].mov[1].beneficiario, user[0].mov[1].bonifico);
```

Remember that you need a new malloc for every `user[i]` that you use.